# Unidirectional DB first many to many with map still seems to want a navigation property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

The application uses EF 6.1 against a pre-existing database.

I have a unidirectional many to many relationship from (class names have been changed to make this example sillier) `Fans` to `Celebrities`. e.g. each instance of a `Fan` follows one or more `Celebrities`, but each instance of a `Celebrity`doesn't track which `Fans` follow said `Celebrity`.

To that end the `Fan` class has a navigation property to `ICollection<Celebrity>`, but not vice versa. As you can see from the map class below, a composite table links the two.

Unfortunately, `var celebrities = db.Celebrities.ToList();` gets me the error:

```
Invalid column name 'Fan_Id'.
```

Could someone please tell me what I've done wrong? I have a number of unidirectional one-to-many relationships in the same application that work. A (somewhat) abbreviated rundown of the entities and their maps:

```
public class Celebrity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // by design, no navigation property to ICollection<Fan>
}

public class Fan
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Celebrity> FollowedCelebrities { get; set; }
}

public class CelebrityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Celebrity>
{
    public CelebrityMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);
        ToTable("Celebrities");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("CelebrityId");
        Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Name");
    }
}

public class FanMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Fan>
{
    public FanMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);
        ToTable("Fans");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("FanId");
        Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");

        HasMany(t => t.FollowedCelebrities)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("FanCelebrityAssignments");
                m.MapLeftKey("FanId");
                m.MapRightKey("CelebrityId");
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about how to fix this but the exception means it supposes there is some `Fan_Id` column created in the table `Celebrity` (but of course not any present). Somehow it assumes the relationship between `Fan-Celebrity` is `one-many` (while it should be `many-many`). I can see you tried to configure the relationship as `many-many` inside the `FanMap` but not sure if that's enough.

Comment: Have you verified that the DB has all migrations applied? It sounds like you tried a different configuration, applied that to the DB, but didn't rollback / undo it correctly. Or something.

Comment: Yeah, or something. I figured it out, see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'd love to delete the question and slink away, I'll leave it up for future reference and other apparent EF noobs like me.

In my data context class there is an `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` override, and in this override there are many map classes assigned to  `modelBuilder.Configurations`.

Unfortunately, while `FanMap` exists, it was not one of those classes added to `Configurations`. I added it and things now work properly.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. This was going to bug me all day!